# Ordenar por dia da semana e horario

Tags: sql

Quero ordenar pelo dia da semana e hora

os dados estão vindo da seguinte maneira:

```
id, dia_hora
1   SEG-10h
2   QUI-11h
3   SEX-09h
```

query que funciona quando recebe apenas as siglas sem hora:

```
SELECT id,dia FROM minhatabela ORDER BY (
   FIELD(dia, 'DOM', 'SEG', 'TER', 'QUA', 'QUI', 'SEX', 'SAB')
)
```

Comment: Dois dados diferentes na mesma coluna, não seria melhor separar isso?

Comment: acho que seria inviável dado o tamanho do sistema que já está pronto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sempre os dias voltarem com 3 caracteres você pode usar `SUBSTRING()`

`SELECT id,dia FROM minhatabela ORDER BY (
   FIELD(SUBSTRING(dia,1,3), 'DOM', 'SEG', 'TER', 'QUA', 'QUI', 'SEX', 'SAB')
   , SUBSTRING(dia,3,3)
)`

Comment: funcionou, posso usar 2 field com substring um para a sigla outro pra hora?

Comment: Sim só separar por "," já edito

Comment: obrigado cara :)